# BackboneJS if else condition in templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have the following code in my BackboneJS template (rendered using Underscore)

```
<input type="radio" class="isMale" id="isMaleVolunteersNo" 
    <%= model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == undefined ||         
        model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == null || 
        model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == 'N' ? 'checked' : '' 
     %>                 
     name="isMaleVolunteers" value="false" />
<label for="isMaleVolunteersNo" style="display:inline">No</label>
```

When the model attribute isMaleVolunteers is undefined, I want the No to be checked by default.

I tried the following (with paranthesis)...still does not work;

```
<input type="radio" class="isMale" id="isMaleVolunteersNo" 
    <%= (model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == undefined ||
         model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == null || 
         model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == 'N') ? 'checked' : '' 
    %> 
    name="isMaleVolunteers" value="false" />
<label for="isMaleVolunteersNo" style="display:inline">No</label>
```

But the above code does not work. Is there any issue with the code ?

Comment: Surround your if conditions in parenthesis, so from the first `isMaleVolenteers` condition up to the `?`

Comment: tried with parenthesis...still does not work...

Comment: may be you just have to write normal `if` and remove `=` at the beginning of `<`

Comment: When you say "does not work" what does that mean?

Comment: @testndtv Are you sure that `model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers` is not an empty string in that case radio button would not be checked.

Answer (score 5):

In Underscore Template's use `<% %>` to execute javascript code. `<%= %>` is used to interpolate variables(in short print variables)
So your code should look something like `<input type="radio" <%if(condition){print('checked');}%> >`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" class="isMale" id="isMaleVolunteersNo" 
   <%= 
   !model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers  || model.attributes.isMaleVolunteers == 'N' 
   ? 'checked' 
   : '' %> 
   name="isMaleVolunteers" value="false" 
/>
<label for="isMaleVolunteersNo" style="display:inline">No</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, since you're using backbone models you don't need to check for null or undefined, you can just use the API method [model.has()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-has) — So in this case the code could look something like this

```
<input type="radio" <%= !!(model.has('isMaleVolunteersNo') && model.get('isMaleVolunteersNo') !== 'N') ? 'checked' : '' %> class="..." id="..." name="...">
```

As a rule of thumb, if you have to access `model.attributes` manually you're doing something wrong. Also, a good practise is to turn your models into JSON before running them through the template, as that makes the data easier to work with.